# Can't show rounded corners on custom panel skin

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, panel, skinning

I'm fairly new to Flex 4.0. I wanted to change the background color of my Panel title area and  I discovered that I needed to create custom skin or skin extender to accomplish this.  So I created a skin called myPanelSkin based upon the Spark.PanelSkin.  My background color works fine but it will no longer show the cornerRadius defined either on the component or in a style.

I then tried another approach and simply created a new skin as an exact copy of the Spark.PanelSkin. It also looses the cornerRadius.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem.  It seemed so much easier in Flex 3.  Thanks.

Comment: Please place your skin 1 and skin 2 listings in question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default skin and set its themeColor.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use CSS in flex 4, here's an example for round corners:

```
    s|Panel
{
    skin-class: ClassReference('skins.panda.DraggablePanel');
    border-alpha: 0;
    corner-radius: 5;
}
```

The *skin-class* css property is the skin reference of the *Spark Panel* in Flex 4. But just focus on the **corner-radius** property, set them to any radius you like and you'll see the sweet round corner. **:)**